# how to properly read excel files with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to read all `.xlsx` files for an specific directory, the idea is to load every excel spreadsheet for every directory files, store them as a `.pandas` dataframe and then store each spreadsheet for all reports as a dictionary.

In my attempt, the error `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` keeps arising,

What am I missing?

**Read Reports and concatenate for every excel sheet**:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

############### path settlement and file names ##########
path_reportes = 'Reports/xlsx_folder'
file_names = os.listdir(path_reportes)
overall_df = dict()

############## concatenate all reports ##################

for file_name in file_names:
    data_file_path = os.path.join(path_reportes, file_name)
    
    # Start by opening the spreadsheet and selecting the main sheet
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=data_file_path)
    #sheet = workbook.active

    # Save the spreadsheet
    workbook.save(filename=data_file_path)
    df_report_dict = pd.read_excel(data_file_path, sheet_name=None, engine='openpyxl')
    
    for key in df_report_dict:
        df_report_dict[key]['report_name'] = file_name
        try:
            overall_df[key] = overall_df[key].append(df_report_dict[key], ignore_index=True)
        except:
            overall_df[key] = df_report_dict[key]
```

Which output the next error:

> BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

*Full traceback error*:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5e32988240ae> in <module>
     10 
     11     # Start by opening the spreadsheet and selecting the main sheet
---> 12     workbook = load_workbook(filename=data_file_path)
     13     #sheet = workbook.active
     14 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    314     """
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
--> 316                         data_only, keep_links)
    317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in __init__(self, fn, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    122     def __init__(self,  fn, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
    123                   data_only=False, keep_links=True):
--> 124         self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
    125         self.valid_files = self.archive.namelist()
    126         self.read_only = read_only

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in _validate_archive(filename)
     94             raise InvalidFileException(msg)
     95 
---> 96     archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
     97     return archive
     98 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
   1129         try:
   1130             if mode == 'r':
-> 1131                 self._RealGetContents()
   1132             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1133                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1199         if self.debug > 1:
   1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: All XLSX files must be zipfiles so there is probably a problem with some of your files.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your experiment and created dummy excel files and after little modification to your code, I didn't get your error. try the code bellow to see if it solve your problem:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

############### path settlement and file names ##########
path_reportes = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Reports', 'xlsx_folder')
file_names = os.listdir(path_reportes)
overall_df = dict()

############## concatenate all reports ##################

for file_name in file_names:
    data_file_path = os.path.join(path_reportes, file_name)
    
    # Start by opening the spreadsheet and selecting the main sheet
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=data_file_path)
    #sheet = workbook.active

    # Save the spreadsheet
    workbook.save(filename=data_file_path)
    df_report_dict = pd.read_excel(data_file_path, sheet_name=None, engine='openpyxl')
    
    for key in df_report_dict:
        df_report_dict[key]['report_name'] = file_name
        try:
            overall_df[key] = overall_df[key].append(df_report_dict[key], ignore_index=True)
        except:
            overall_df[key] = df_report_dict[key]
```

Comment: Hey @Thulfiqar, I just checked what was going on with the `.xlsx` files, some of them are corrupted

Comment: he excel warning message when trying to open says: `Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`

Comment: yes it's either the files corrupted or there is a problem with reading the files; I assumed the files are ok. glad you solved the issue :)